# convergence of test functions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbf R^n)$ such that $0\leq \phi(x)\leq 1$ and $\phi(x)=1$ for $|x|\leq 1$ and $\phi(x)=0$ for $|x|\geq 2$. Defining $\phi_n(x)=\phi(x/n)$. How do we show that $\phi_n\rightarrow \phi$ pointwise as $n\rightarrow\infty$ to conclude that $\phi_nf\rightarrow\phi f$ pointwise for any integrable function $f$?

Comment: Doesn't $\phi_n\to 1$ pointwise?

Comment: $\phi_n$ converges pointwise to the constant $1$. Thus $\phi_nf \to f$ pointwise, and if $f \in L^p,\, p <\infty$, also in $L^p$.

Comment: Thanks, but can you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $\phi(x) = 1$ for $\lvert x\rvert \leqslant 1$, we have $\phi_n(x) = 1$ for all $x$ with $\lvert x/n\rvert \leqslant 1$, or, written in a different way, $\lvert x\rvert \leqslant n$. So, for every $x$, almost all $\phi_n$ have $\phi_n(x) = 1$, thus $\phi_n \to 1$ pointwise.

And therefore we also have $\phi_n\cdot f \to f$ pointwise for every function $f$. When $f \in L^p$, for $p <\infty$, then the convergence is not only pointwise, but also $L^p$-convergence, thus such a sequence of cut-off functions can serve to approximate any integrable ($L^p,\,p<\infty$) function by integrable ($L^p$) functions *with compact support* (and smooth, if $f$ is smooth). Such approximations are often useful, for example because many theorems can be proved more easily for functions with compact support, and then extended to the general case by continuity.

Comment: Daniel thanks. What happens when $n\leq|x|\leq 2n$? I ask this question because if I have remember correctly, in some sources I have seen that such sequences converges to a characteristic function $\chi_{[-1, 1]}$.

Comment: That's the region where $\phi_n$ drops to $0$. Without knowing more about $\phi$, all we can say is that $0 \leqslant \phi_n(x) \leqslant 1$ for $n < \lvert x\rvert < 2n$, and the values drop smoothly from $1$ to $0$ there.